# How to set a name to uploaded file instead of random numbers by using carbon in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

When I upload an image it set as random numbers like //15215653352.png. But instead I have my images must be precise , and that means I have a folder which has the pictures set organized(digital_1.png,digital_2.png,digital_3.png...)

##The folder of images is in public called imagg##

Inside the productFactory I'm using this :
 `'image' => 'digital_'.$this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,28).'.png',`

To add a picture I have this code :

```
$imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp.'.'. $this->image->extension();
        $this->image->storeAs('imagg',$imageName,'public');
        $product->image = $imageName;
```

The items-component.blade.php:

```
  @foreach ($products as $product)
        <!-- grid item #1 -->
        <a href="{{route('product.details',$product->slug)}}">
        <div id="TEST" class="activities-grid-item bla" style=" background-image: url({{asset('imagg')}}/{{$product->image}}"  >

          <h1 class="activities-h1">
.
.
.
</a>
$endforeach
```

the filesystem.php:

`'root' => storage_path('app'),`

So therefore the images cannot be displayed with those random numbers but they must be named suc has digital_x.png (while x is variable from 1 to 28 , and existed in the imagg folder).

Comment: you can get count the images in the dir and just + 1 for the name.

Comment: it must be displayd as digital_

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
 try {
    $dir = 'folder/to_the_images/'; // path to the images
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $images = glob($dir . '{*.jpg, *.JPG, *.jpeg}');
        $imageName = 'digital_' . count($images) + 1 . '.' . $this->image->extension();
        $this->image->storeAs('imagg', $imageName, 'public');
        $product->image = $imageName;
    }
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    die('saving images failed ' . $exception->getMessage());
}
```